# Scrolling a collection view with a circular layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I use the code from this blog post: http://markpospesel.wordpress.com/2012/10/25/fixing-circlelayout/ (Code on github: https://github.com/mpospese/CircleLayout)

It is basically a modified version of the CircleLayout project provided by Apple at WWDC.

What I'd like to do, is add scrolling capability to the circular collection view. Or maybe it should be called rotating.

I'm gonna place the collection view off the screen at the bottom, so that you can only see the top third of it. And scrolling by swiping the wheel let's the user see all items.

How can I do that? Does the collection view support scrolling by default, or do I have to add a recogniser and do stuff manually?

Comment: I went with iCarousel as suggest below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think iCarousel is a good choice for you:
https://github.com/nicklockwood/iCarousel
Use Wheel type.

Answer (score 1):

I have developed an custom UICollectionviewLayout, which layout's the collection view cells in an circular layout. It can be configured to show an particular.

In your case you would be needing an 180 - 0 degrees.

https://github.com/DoddaSrinivasan/DSCircularCollectionView